# Nested for loops to Java 8 Stream API representation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Recently I have decided to look into Java 8 by refactoring simple pieces of code. 
I have following example which I am trying to convert into Java 8 representation.

```
public static void halfTriangle(){
        for(int i=1; i<=4; i++){
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
```

I have managed to come up with something like this:

```
public static void halfTriangleJava8(){
        IntStream.range(1, 5)
            .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(1, 5)
                .forEach(j -> System.out.println("* "))
        );
    }
```

but I have no idea where I could place remaining:

```
System.out.println(" ");
```

I have tried something like:

```
public static void halfTriangleJava8(){
        IntStream.range(1, 5)
            .forEach(i -> {
                IntStream.range(1, 5);
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
                .forEach(j -> System.out.println("* "))
        );
    }
```

But it gives me an error which I don't fully understand.
"The target type for this expression must be a functional interface".

I believe it's a very simple error but I have only started looking into Java 8 today so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are `for` statements deprecated in Java 8?

Comment: No I am just looking at more elegant and up to date way of doing it.

Comment: So `for` statements are obsolete?

Comment: Your first snippet is much more elegant than what you could do with Streams, **imo** (<-- and this is the problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not going to be more elegant but you can have:

```
public static void halfTriangleJava8(){
    IntStream.range(1, 5).forEach(i -> {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i).forEach(j -> System.out.print("* "));
        System.out.println(" ");
    });
}
```

Althought for those sorts of problems, it'd be better to keep a good-old `for` loop.

A somewhat prettier way would be to map each integer into the `String` to be printed at the corresponding line:

```
public static void halfTriangleJava8(){
    IntStream.range(1, 5)
             .mapToObj(i -> String.join(" ", Collections.nCopies(i, "*")))
             .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however your first snippet doesn't print the half triangle. Second do, thank you.

Comment: @Raikonne Hmm, I just tested it and it print the correct output. Did you take all of the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `{}` braces; and you might use [`IntStream.rangeClosed(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) so you can keep the same indices. Something like,

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).forEach(i -> {
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i).forEach(j -> System.out.print("* "));
    System.out.println();
});
```